# vector initialization using eigen library

Tags: c++, eigen

I am going through the documentation of Eigen library at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html

and I found the example given below

- Eigen::VectorXd v(10);
- v[0] = 0.1;
- v[1] = 0.2;
- v(0) = 0.3;
- v(1) = 0.4;

I could not understand the difference between v(1) and v[1] usage as one uses square bracket and other uses a different one.

What difference does it make ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`[1]` is the same as `(1)` when it's supported, but parens support multiple dimensions like `(1,2)` and brackets are only available for one-dimensional `Vector` objects.

For uniformity, it's usually better just to stick with `()` parens.

These are for general access. For initialization in particular, see also the `<<` … `,` operator.

Comment: sorry, cannot understand what you meant. Can you give an example ? Thanks

Comment: @Sai Added a little detail. I cannot give an example of usage of `[]` because I don't know of any. Always use `()`. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Actually both operators `[]` and `()` do bounds checking. The difference is that `[]` is for vectors only, while `()` gives access to the underlying array (contrary to your answer) and can be used with matrices.

Comment: @Ruslan I meant the C/C++ array, not the Eigen `Array` class which implements dynamic multidimensional indexing. I can't find, at the moment, documentation for either `operator()` or `operator[]` and I don't have Eigen installed right now. Are you saying that `[]` is exactly the same as `()` but only defined for one-dimensional classes, or only for `Vector`?

Comment: According to [their docs](http://tinyurl.com/oknbpj7), `operator()(index)` is synonymous to `operator[](index)`. But if you look at [the source](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/DenseCoeffsBase_8h_source.html#l00149) (lines 149-175), you'll see that `operator[]` explicitly does a static assert checking that `*this` is a vector, while `operator()` doesn't.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks. Apparently I remembered wrong when I wrote this answer. Fixed now.